# Query running long despite having "good" plan

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a query which is a UNION query which joins multiple tables. All the stats are updated. The query used to run fine and completed within 30-40 seconds but in 12c it's taking insane amount of time(~10 mins to 5 mins)

I have captured the actual plan.

```
lan hash value: 1038754298

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                        | Name                   | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | Reads  |  OMem |  1Mem |  O/1/M   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                                 |                        |      1 |        |     50 |00:00:49.93 |     960K|      7 |       |       |          |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                                   |                        |      1 |   1791 |     50 |00:00:49.93 |     960K|      7 |   267K|   267K|     1/0/0|
|   2 |   UNION-ALL                                      |                        |      1 |        |   2648 |00:00:49.93 |     960K|      7 |       |       |          |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS SEMI                             |                        |      1 |      1 |   2648 |00:00:42.36 |     498K|      0 |       |       |          |
|*  4 |     HASH JOIN                                    |                        |      1 |   1589 |   9111 |00:00:42.22 |     469K|      0 |  7900K|  2299K|     1/0/0|
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN                                   |                        |      1 |   1140K|  50569 |00:00:19.50 |     342K|      0 |  8321K|  2379K|     1/0/0|
|*  6 |       HASH JOIN                                  |                        |      1 |  44335 |  59660 |00:00:16.01 |     252K|      0 |  1817K|  1817K|     1/0/0|
|*  7 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL                         | PROMHEAD               |      1 |    870 |    870 |00:00:00.01 |     602 |      0 |       |       |          |
|*  8 |        HASH JOIN                                 |                        |      1 |   1168K|    172K|00:00:15.94 |     251K|      0 |  1148K|  1148K|     1/0/0|
|*  9 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL                        | PRICE_BATCH_TRAN       |      1 |    857 |    857 |00:00:00.01 |     315 |      0 |       |       |          |
|  10 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL                        | PROMSTORE              |      1 |     36M|     36M|00:00:04.64 |     251K|      0 |       |       |          |
|* 11 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL                          | PROMSKU                |      1 |   6665K|   6665K|00:00:01.49 |   90224 |      0 |       |       |          |
|  12 |      PARTITION RANGE ALL                         |                        |      1 |     37M|     37M|00:00:10.72 |     127K|      0 |       |       |          |
|  13 |       INDEX FAST FULL SCAN                       | PK_ITEM_ZONE_PRICE     |     24 |     37M|     37M|00:00:04.75 |     127K|      0 |       |       |          |
|  14 |     PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR                     |                        |   9111 |  32376 |   2648 |00:00:00.13 |   28752 |      0 |       |       |          |
|  15 |      PARTITION HASH ITERATOR                     |                        |   9111 |  32376 |   2648 |00:00:00.11 |   28752 |      0 |       |       |          |
|* 16 |       TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED  | FDT_PRICE_FUTURE       |   9111 |  32376 |   2648 |00:00:00.09 |   28752 |      0 |       |       |          |
|* 17 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN                          | FDT_PRICE_FUTURE_PK    |   9111 |      1 |   2668 |00:00:00.07 |   26089 |      0 |       |       |          |
|* 18 |    HASH JOIN                                     |                        |      1 |   1790 |      0 |00:00:07.31 |     450K|      7 |  1599K|  1599K|     1/0/0|
|  19 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                            | PRICE_SUSP_HEAD        |      1 |   2056 |   2056 |00:00:00.01 |     965 |      0 |       |       |          |
|* 20 |     HASH JOIN                                    |                        |      1 |   1912 |      0 |00:00:07.30 |     449K|      7 |    39M|  8299K|     1/0/0|
|  21 |      PART JOIN FILTER CREATE                     | :BF0000                |      1 |    745K|    745K|00:00:00.12 |    1682 |      0 |       |       |          |
|  22 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL                          | PRICE_ZONE_GROUP_STORE |      1 |    745K|    745K|00:00:00.03 |    1682 |      0 |       |       |          |
|* 23 |      HASH JOIN                                   |                        |      1 |    496K|      0 |00:00:07.03 |     448K|      7 |    73M|  6638K|     1/0/0|
|  24 |       PARTITION RANGE ALL                        |                        |      1 |   1138K|   1138K|00:00:01.70 |     154K|      7 |       |       |          |
|  25 |        PARTITION HASH ALL                        |                        |     26 |   1138K|   1138K|00:00:01.53 |     154K|      7 |       |       |          |
|  26 |         TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED| FDT_PRICE_FUTURE       |    208 |   1138K|   1138K|00:00:01.35 |     154K|      7 |       |       |          |
|* 27 |          INDEX SKIP SCAN                         | FDT_PRICE_FUTURE_I1    |    208 |   1138K|   1138K|00:00:00.89 |     125K|      7 |       |       |          |
|* 28 |       HASH JOIN                                  |                        |      1 |     25M|      0 |00:00:04.84 |     293K|      0 |   977K|   977K|     1/0/0|
|* 29 |        HASH JOIN                                 |                        |      1 |    252K|   1123 |00:00:03.33 |   90826 |      0 |  1344K|  1344K|     1/0/0|
|* 30 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL                        | PROMHEAD               |      1 |    870 |    870 |00:00:00.01 |     602 |      0 |       |       |          |
|* 31 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL                        | PROMSKU                |      1 |   6665K|   6665K|00:00:01.47 |   90224 |      0 |       |       |          |
|  32 |        PARTITION RANGE JOIN-FILTER               |                        |      1 |   6719K|  32778 |00:00:01.51 |     202K|      0 |       |       |          |
|* 33 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL                        | PRICE_SUSP_DETAIL      |     24 |   6719K|  32778 |00:00:01.51 |     202K|      0 |       |       |          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - access("IZP"."ITEM"="PSK"."SKU" AND "IZP"."ZONE_GROUP_ID"="PBT"."ZONE_GROUP_ID" AND "IZP"."ZONE_ID"="PBT"."NEW_ZONE_ID")
   5 - access("PS"."PROMOTION"="PSK"."PROMOTION")
   6 - access("PH"."PROMOTION"="PS"."PROMOTION")
   7 - filter("PH"."STATUS"='A')
   8 - access("PS"."STORE"="PBT"."STORE")
       filter("PS"."START_DATE">"PBT"."EFFECTIVE_DATE")
   9 - filter("PBT"."FDC_STATUS"='A')
  11 - filter(("PSK"."CHANGE_TYPE"='MA' OR "PSK"."CHANGE_TYPE"='PC'))
  16 - filter("PRICE_MOD_TYPE"='ZC')
  17 - access("STORE"="PS"."STORE" AND "SKU"="PSK"."SKU" AND "START_DATE"<"PS"."START_DATE")
  18 - access("PSH"."PRICE_CHANGE"="PSD"."PRICE_CHANGE")
       filter("FDT"."START_DATE">"PSH"."ACTIVE_DATE")
  20 - access("PSD"."ZONE_ID"="PZGS"."ZONE_ID" AND "PSD"."ZONE_GROUP_ID"="PZGS"."ZONE_GROUP_ID" AND "FDT"."STORE"="PZGS"."STORE")
  23 - access("PSK"."PROMOTION"="FDT"."PRICE_MOD_NO" AND "PSD"."SKU"="FDT"."SKU")
  27 - access("FDT"."PRICE_MOD_TYPE"='PR')
       filter("FDT"."PRICE_MOD_TYPE"='PR')
  28 - access("PSK"."SKU"="PSD"."SKU")
  29 - access("PH"."PROMOTION"="PSK"."PROMOTION")
  30 - filter("PH"."STATUS"='A')
  31 - filter(("PSK"."CHANGE_TYPE"='MA' OR "PSK"."CHANGE_TYPE"='PC'))
  33 - filter("PSD"."STATUS"='A')

Note
-----
   - this is an adaptive plan
```

As you can see Oracle predicts the cardinality correctly in most cases. Can you suggest where should I start looking from.

```
    SELECT  
        PBT.STORE                                                                                                                                                                                                                ,
        PSK.SKU                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ,

        0 MULTI_UNITS                                                                                                                                                                                                            ,
        0 MULTI_UNIT_RETAIL                                                                                                                                                                                                      ,
        PS.START_DATE PS_START_DATE                                                                                                                                                                                              ,
        PBT.EFFECTIVE_DATE PC_ACTIVE_DATE                                                                                                                                                                                        ,
        PBT.ZONE_CHANGE PRICE_CHANGE                                                                                                                                                                                             ,
        PH.PROMOTION PRICE_MOD_NO                                                                                                                                                                                                ,
        'PR' PRICE_TYPE                                                                                                                                                                                                          ,
        'U' REC_TYPE
FROM    PROMHEAD PH         ,
        PROMSTORE PS        ,
        PROMSKU PSK         ,
        PRICE_BATCH_TRAN PBT,
        ITEM_ZONE_PRICE IZP
WHERE   PH.PROMOTION         =PS.PROMOTION
        AND PS.PROMOTION     =PSK.PROMOTION
        AND PBT.FDC_STATUS   ='A'
        AND PH.STATUS        ='A'
        AND PS.STORE         =PBT.STORE
        AND PSK.CHANGE_TYPE IN('MA','PC')
        AND IZP.ITEM         =PSK.SKU
        AND IZP.ZONE_GROUP_ID=PBT.ZONE_GROUP_ID
        AND IZP.ZONE_ID      =PBT.NEW_ZONE_ID
        AND PS.START_DATE    > PBT.EFFECTIVE_DATE
        AND EXISTS
        (
                SELECT  1
                FROM    FDT_PRICE_FUTURE
                WHERE   SKU                =PSK.SKU
                        AND STORE          =PS.STORE
                        AND START_DATE     < PS.START_DATE
                        AND PRICE_MOD_TYPE = 'ZC'
        )
UNION ALL
SELECT  FDT.STORE                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ,
        FDT.SKU                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ,

        0 MULTI_UNITS                                                                                                                                                                                                               ,
        0 MULTI_UNIT_RETAIL                                                                                                                                                                                                         ,
        FDT.START_DATE PS_START_DATE                                                                                                                                                                                                ,
        PSH.ACTIVE_DATE PC_ACTIVE_DATE                                                                                                                                                                                              ,
        PSD.PRICE_CHANGE PRICE_CHANGE                                                                                                                                                                                               ,
        PH.PROMOTION PRICE_MOD_NO                                                                                                                                                                                                   ,
        'PR' PRICE_TYPE                                                                                                                                                                                                             ,
        'U' REC_TYPE
FROM    FDT_PRICE_FUTURE FDT ,
        PROMHEAD PH          ,
        PROMSKU PSK          ,
        PRICE_SUSP_DETAIL PSD,
        PRICE_SUSP_HEAD PSH  ,
        PRICE_ZONE_GROUP_STORE PZGS
WHERE   PH.PROMOTION          =PSK.PROMOTION
        AND PSK.PROMOTION     =FDT.PRICE_MOD_NO
        AND FDT.PRICE_MOD_TYPE='PR'
        AND PH.STATUS         ='A'
        AND PSH.PRICE_CHANGE  =PSD.PRICE_CHANGE
        AND PSD.STATUS        ='A'
        AND PSD.ZONE_ID       =PZGS.ZONE_ID
        AND PSD.ZONE_GROUP_ID =PZGS.ZONE_GROUP_ID
        AND FDT.STORE         =PZGS.STORE
        AND PSK.SKU           =PSD.SKU
        AND PSD.SKU           =FDT.SKU
        AND PSK.CHANGE_TYPE  IN('MA','PC')
        AND FDT.START_DATE    > PSH.ACTIVE_DATE
ORDER BY 1,2,7;
```

Comment: I would start with a [SQL Monitor report](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/manageability/sqlmonitor-084401.html), and also check ASH data if licensed.

Comment: i would bet on the EXISTS

Comment: EXISTS working well only when you are sorting a small set not a "millioned"

Comment: think about that, oracle sets the resultset without the exists, and after that he needs to check for every single row the condition (in the exists)

Comment: use left join instead of exists when the resultset(!without the exists!) is above a few thousands of rows

Comment: have you compared the 11g and the 12c explain plans to see what is different?  Perhaps a full table scan in 12c that was an index lookup in 11g.  I've seen similar before.  Small threshold changes in the cost values the optimizer uses.  Having a baseline plan would help keep consistency of the plan.

Comment: The plan says the total `A-Time` is 49.93 seconds so I assume the query plan is from 11g.  Capture the 12c plan in the same way and the A-Time may tell you where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if Diagnostics and Tuning Pack licenses available, you can run the SQL Tuning Advisor on the SQL.

```
-- SQLTUNE.sql
-- Updated 04-Mar-2015 RDCornejo for spool error 
-- takes sql_id,plan_hash_value, start and ent snap_id's as parameters
-- created sql tuning report on c:\temp

set echo off
set feedback off
set term off 
set verify off 
set head on

-- uncomment for debugging if neeed
-- set echo on term on


set termout on
accept SQL_ID     char prompt 'Enter the sql_id to Tune? '
accept hash_value char prompt 'Enter the hash_value to Tune? '
accept BEGIN_SNAP char prompt 'Enter the begin snap_id to Tune? '
accept END_SNAP   char prompt 'Enter the end   snap_id to Tune? '

-- using bind variables:
variable sql_id_var      varchar2(25);
variable plan_hash_value varchar2(25);
variable begin_snap_var  varchar2(25);
variable end_snap_var    varchar2(25);
variable task_name       varchar2(100);

exec :sql_id_var      := '&SQL_ID';
exec :plan_hash_value := '&hash_value';
exec :begin_snap_var  := '&BEGIN_SNAP';
exec :end_snap_var    := '&END_SNAP';
exec :task_name       := :sql_id_var || '_' ||  :plan_hash_value || '_AWR';

column sql_id     format a25
column plan_hash_value format 999999999999
column begin_snap format a10
column end_snap   format a10

select :sql_id_var as sql_id 
, :plan_hash_value as plan_hash_value
, :begin_snap_var  as begin_snap
, :end_snap_var    as end_snap
from dual;

-- get my prefered text in file name
column MY_TEXT new_val FILE_NAME noprint

Select instance_name||'_'|| :SQL_ID_VAR || '_' || :plan_hash_value|| '_' || :BEGIN_SNAP_VAR || '_' ||  :END_SNAP_VAR || '_' || to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy_mm_dd_hh24_mi')  MY_TEXT 
from 
(select upper(substr(global_name, 1, instr(global_name,'.' )-1)) instance_name from global_name);

-- turn spooling on to capture any error and the report.
set serveroutput on

spool c:\temp\AWR_Tuning_Task_&FILE_NAME..txt


set linesize 210 
set pagesize 9999
set long 10000000
set time on
set timing on
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON


prompt Drop existing task if exists.  Ignore error if not
-- Drop existig tuning task; assuming I'm running new tasks and if one exists, it it no longer needed; can ignore error if no task exists yet
execute  DBMS_SQLTUNE.drop_tuning_task (task_name => :task_name);



prompt Create Tuning Task
-- Tuning task created for specific a statement from the AWR.   [SEE BELOW FOR EXAPLES USING OTHER METHODS OF IDENTIFYING THE SQL]
--If the TASK_NAME parameter is specified it's value is returned as the SQL tune task identifier. 
--If ommitted a system generated name like "TASK_1478" is returned. 
--If the SCOPE parameter is set to scope_limited the SQL profiling analysis is omitted. 
--The TIME_LIMIT parameter simply restricts the time the optimizer can spend compiling the recommendations.
/**/
DECLARE
  l_sql_tune_task_id  VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  l_sql_tune_task_id := DBMS_SQLTUNE.create_tuning_task (
                          begin_snap  => to_number(:BEGIN_SNAP_VAR) ,
                          end_snap    => to_number(:END_SNAP_VAR) ,
                          sql_id      => :sql_id_var,
                          plan_hash_value => to_number(:plan_hash_value),
                          scope       => DBMS_SQLTUNE.scope_comprehensive,
                          time_limit  => 1200, -- in seconds
                          task_name   => :task_name,
                          description => 'Tuning task for statement '|| :sql_id_var || ' hash: ' || :plan_hash_value|| ' in AWR ' || :BEGIN_SNAP_VAR || ' - ' || :END_SNAP_VAR || ' .');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('l_sql_tune_task_id: ' || l_sql_tune_task_id);
END;
/

prompt Execute Tuning Task
-- With the tuning task defined the next step is to execute it using the EXECUTE_TUNING_TASK procedure.
EXEC DBMS_SQLTUNE.execute_tuning_task(task_name => :task_name);
/**/

-- Once the tuning task has executed successfully the recommendations can be displayed using the REPORT_TUNING_TASK function.
set linesize 210 
set pagesize 9999
set long 10000000
set time on
set timing on
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

-- width of output should not need more than 200
column recommendations format a200

prompt Report Tuning Task
SELECT DBMS_SQLTUNE.report_tuning_task(:task_name) AS recommendations FROM dual;



spool off
```

Comment: DBAs have implemented SQL profile as of now but we need to come up with something permanent

Comment: @redsoxlost, Did you ever consider that there is no such thing as permanent.  The only way to figure this out is to find out what statistics adjustments the SQL profile is using and try to get your stats gather process to mimic it.  In my experience this is very difficult and not worth the time as you can likely get a new SQL Profile if the performance degrades.

Comment: thanks for your input  Does SQL profile auto update if it gets a better plan?

Comment: @redsoxlost, In our environment, we run the SQL Tuning Advisor (STA) manually when issues crop up.  I know that the STA runs nightly, so it will probably be picked up.  I think you can set the DB to automatically accept the SQL Profiles or baselines, but since we don't do it in my co. I can't tell you how to do it.